# Get information from object "this" javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm trying to retrieve the numbers that generates from this code:

```
$("#100wattaren")
    .countdown("2018/01/01", function(event) {
    $(this).text(
    event.strftime('%D dagar %H timmar %M minuter %S sekunder')
    );
});
```

If I console.log "this" it outputs the actual div with information, but I just wants whats inside the div so in this case 93 dagar 05 timmar....

```
<div id="100wattaren" class="award">93 dagar 05 timmar 12 minuter 02 sekunder</div>
```

I use the jQuery addon: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

Comment: You want to *log* just the text? `console.log($(this).text())`.

Comment: OMG that was simple, thank you @tadman that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of jQuery functions have dual use, mutator *and* accessor. If you call them with an argument they change values, with no argument simply returns what's there.

So to log the contents without altering it:

```
console.log($(this).text());
```